# Samsung Charge RECORD_SOUND_ACTION Intent not returning when started for result

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that involves having the user record audio.  I'm using the following intent to call the Audio Recorder.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
startActivityForResult(intent, AUDIO_REQ);
```

While this works fine on the emulator and nearly all devices it's been tested on, when I try to run it on a Samsung Charge the Audio Recorder never gives me the option to save the recording and return to my Activity.  Once the recording is complete, I'm sent to a list of all recorded audio on the device, and selecting any from this list just plays them.  I can return to the calling Activity with the back button, but this causes a `RESULT_CANCLED` result code, no file is created at `path,` and the `data` parameter of onActivityResult is null. (data is still null if I remove the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` extra from the intent, nothing changes in this case)

Does anyone know of a way to make the Audio Recorder on this device act correctly? Or can anyone at least confirm that this is solely a Samsung Charge issue, and not something I'll have to worry about on many devices?

Comment: did you a find a solution to this yet.

Comment: Nope, but I'll update this question if I do.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is (an ignorant) bug in a customized implementation of the audio recorder for that device.  Maybe it's possible that you could detect the device and if present write your own audio recording GUI?  As a long-term alternative you could report this to Samsung.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm with the same problem on a Samsung Galaxy S SCL. So this issue can happen in many devices. Maybe the best solution is to implement your own recorder instead of using an Intent to the built-in... But not as suggested above (I assume is better to have an unified interface for the app, and not a different one for each device. So if you've to write your own recording GUI, why don't use it to all devices?).

So anyway, if you found the way to go back from the recorder and get the data, it will be nice if you post it here. Thanks

Comment: I ended up rolling my own Audio Recorder, as suggested.  Not sure if this issue ever got a fix, but the phone is a few generations old now so I doubt there will be any more relevant info.