# android MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION: no activity found to handle intent

Tags: android, android-intent, event-handling, record, audio

I try to record sound. I use Intent to record sound. But on one device MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION returns error:

This is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_RECORDING);
```

This is my error:

`No activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND (has extras) }`

What can be the reason ? Does it mean that function is not accesible on some devices ?
How can I check if RECORD_SOUND_ACTION is present on device ?

Comment: What device by the way are you using?

Comment: Small tablet Colorovo 7" City Tab with android 4. The cheapest one on the market at this moment. On  other  devices everything ok.

Comment: no activity found either on Nexus 7

Answer (score 3):

Maybe that device doesn't have any application which allows you to record an audio. Check first if it has a default audio recorder.

According to another post ([Samsung Charge RECORD_SOUND_ACTION Intent not returning when started for result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306617/samsung-charge-record-sound-action-intent-not-returning-when-started-for-result)), it may happen to other devices as well and could possibly be a bug.

This might be possible even if your device has a default audio recorder if that application does not does not include a receiver for the **RECORD_SOUND_ACTION** intent nor does not declare any activity in its manifest that will handle the specified intent.

You may handle this intent by implementing your own audio recorder and declare it in your manifest this way(just in case you want to):

```
<activity
    android:name="com.test.AudioRecorder"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

EDIT: Adding an example on how to verify if an activity can receive your intent

From [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#ExampleSend)

```
if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(sendIntent)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code from file this may help you to solved

```
try 
{
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     File file = new File(image.getAbsolutePath());
     String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
     String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

     myIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimetype);
     mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
     // TODO: handle exception
     String data = e.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: This is a very bad answer, not only because it is beside the point but also because it doesn't provide any explanation to address the concern of the OP